# How to make workers to query only local cassandra nodes?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

Suppose I have several machines each having spark worker and cassandra node installed. Is it possible to require each spark worker to query only its local cassandra node (on the same machine), so that no network operation involved when I do joinWithCassandraTable after repartitionByCassandraReplica using spark-cassandra-connector, so each spark worker fetches data from its local storage?

Comment: I suspect that data locality here allows worker to query cassandra node directly where data stored by specifying a token range in a query, so cassandra node can be remote to the worker. I doubt that the worker somehow can figure out that there is a cassandra node on the same machine and it should query it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the Spark-Cassandra connector, the `LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy` handles this work. It prefers local nodes first, then checks for nodes in the same DC. Specifically local nodes are determined using `java.net.NetworkInterface` to find an address in the host list that matches one in the list of local addresses, as follows:

```
private val localAddresses =
  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces.flatMap(_.getInetAddresses).toSet

/** Returns true if given host is local host */
def isLocalHost(host: Host): Boolean = {
  val hostAddress = host.getAddress
  hostAddress.isLoopbackAddress || localAddresses.contains(hostAddress)
}
```

This logic is used in the creation of the query plan, which returns a list of candidate hosts for the query. Regardless of the plan type (token aware or unaware), the first host in the list is always the local host if it exists.

Comment: It'd be awesome to see how the code snippets are used in Spark-Cassandra connector rather than how to find out the local addresses (that's not specific to the case at hand). Mind offering some pointers as links or complete snippets from the code?

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/rstrickland/3e56cf1a2a8817fe8c25) out. The entry point is `newQueryPlan`, which is called for each statement execution.